# Or Constraint for QueryOver

Tags: nhibernate

I want to get all PartitionStates by name where it exactly meets the `partitionName` or starts with it when containing a `.`.

This is the query I have

```
return session.QueryOver<PartitionState>()
        .Where(p => p.Name == partitionName)
        .WhereRestrictionOn(p => p.Name).IsLike(partitionName + ".", MatchMode.Start)
        .OrderBy(p => p.StartDate).Desc
        .Take(1)
        .SingleOrDefault<PartitionState>();
```

The above query produces an AND expression, but i want it to be an OR.

In SQL it should look like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM PartitionState 
WHERE (Name = @partitionName OR Name like @partitionName+'.%') 
ORDER BY StartDate DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is no built in method, but it is possible to pass a restriction into where method.

```
return session.QueryOver<PartitionState>()
        .Where(Restrictions.Or(
              Restrictions.Where<PartitionState>(p => p.Name == partitionName),
              Restrictions.On<PartitionState>(p => p.Name).IsLike(partitionName + ".", MatchMode.Start)))
        .OrderBy(p => p.StartDate)
        .Desc.Take(1)
        .SingleOrDefault<PartitionState>();
```